# closing sloppy questions for being sloppy.

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I wonder what the community thinks of adding the option to close a question when the person who posted it did a really sloppy job. With more and more students using math.SE I believe we see an increase in questions that could make perfectly good sense, and that most of us also immediately understand, but that is written in such a sloppy and careless way that it should not warrant any consideration. I would like to have the option to close such questions even if they are not off-topic, not too localized, or otherwise improper except for the presentation.

Comment: I disagree. If you don't like a question, you can express your displeasure with a downvote.

Comment: Besides, the point is really moot. The list of close reasons is the same network-wide, and its size is strictly controlled. You are not going to persuade SE leadership that in addition to *NaRQ* they need *Sloppy*. [Related answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/7086/)

Comment: @5PM oh, I see. I had no idea that is how it worked. I guess that pretty much closes my own question.

Answer (score 8):

I think the option is already there, to vote for closure as "not a real question," but I would advise against using it. The usual practice here is to try to coax OP into improving the presentation of the question, even to the point of writing, "I think you mean to ask .... Is that right?"

My feeling is that if OP goes 24 hours without meaningful response to comments aimed at clarifying a poorly presented problem, then it's time to close as NARQ.

Comment: Close, OK, but not delete.  Give him a week or so to come back and clarify the question.